# How can I add new options to Jquery UI Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying this for a good while now but I can't seem to add more options to the multiselect.

Even when I try to add a hardcoded piece of information it just doesn't get added. (The headers for Multiselect and JQuery are in a different file).

You can see the link in action here: 
http://www.fakegaming.eu/GoT/index.php?act=selectteam&matchid=3

```
<?php
$matches = new Matches();
$user = new User();
$id = $_GET['matchid'];
$matchinfo = $matches->getmatch($id);
$matchplayers = $matches->getmatchplayers($id);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.localise('ui-multiselect', {/*language: 'en',*/ path: 'script/locale/'});
        $(".multiselect").multiselect();

        $("#add").click(function() {
          $('#players').multiselect('addOptions', 'Test=123');
          alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    });
</script>
Kies hier 10 spelers die mee doen aan de match.<br /> <br />

<form action='index.php?act=createteam' method='post'>
    <select id="players" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="players[]">
    <?php
        foreach($matchplayers as $matchplayer){
            $userinfo = $user->getuserbyid($matchplayer['user_id']);
            if($matchplayer['type'] == 0 OR $matchplayer['type'] == 2){
                $name = $userinfo['EU_username'];
                ?>
                <option value="<?= $name ?>"><?= $name ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }

    ?>
    </select>
    <input name='name' type='text' id='name' />
    <input type='button' id="add" name="add" value="Toevoegen" />
    <input name="submit" value="Maak team" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm probably just doing something horribly wrong but I just want a good multiselect and add some names to it.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't a problem, but have you tried setting `opt.text` and `opt.value` _before_ adding it into `players`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say are using jQuery, but I see very little use of it... Here would be a "jQuery way" of adding an `<OPTION>` to your multiselect

```
$('#players').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', '123').text('345'));
```

To select an attribute :

```
$('#players option[value="123"]').attr('selected', true);
```

to deselect an attribute :

```
$('#players option[value="123"]').removeAttr('selected');
```

to remove an option

```
$('#players option[value="123"]').remove();
```

** **Edit** **

(I didn't look at your reference link. I should be the best to anwser, I'm one of the original authors of this widget!)

There is a next version of this widget that Michael Aufreiter and I worked on that implements more functionality that you require. It is a little unstable with some configurations, but should be stable enough with basic (default) setup.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/michael/multiselect/blob/next/js/ui.multiselect.js) and you can access values via the options :

```
 $('#players').multiselect('addOptions', '123=456'); // value=123, text=456
```

Sorry, the API documentation was not updated to document this. This widget is actually being supported by other contributors and either of us, original authors, maintain this version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hot dog; that is awfully handy you thought to stop by this question. Great answer

Comment: the Github repository has also a demo page, if you mind taking a look at it. Also, you may look at the source code for more glimpse of the features, it is fairly documented. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the link and that option. I just tried it out but whatever I try to do it just doesn't do anything.

I got the script like this right now and the click handler is working but it isn't adding anything to the select.

Updated my question to show current code.

Comment: of course it does nothing, you still have the old .js source file. You must replace the one you have with the one I pointed, because the version you have does not have the functionality you want.

Comment: Actually I did upload the new .js source file :/

Comment: Oh actually it did seem to revert somehow but the new one breaks my code :(

Comment: Ah, I rechecked all my headers and it seems to be working now!
Thanks for your help, just need to try getting it in a array on my next page now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit players to your `index.php?act=createteam` action, make sure you've selected players before sending request.

```
<script>
    function selectPlayers() {
        var opts = document.getElementById("players").options;
        for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
            opts[i].selected = "selected";
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<form action='index.php?act=createteam' method='post' onsubmit='selectPlayers()'>
```